# List all rows, and add an additional field if rows exits in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one with `products` and another with `ratings`.

I want to list all `products` and if a user has rated the product (then r.by is the userId and r.rating is the rating) then I want to add a `userrating`=r.rating else userrating=0 to the SQL response.

It works with only one user, so I don't know what's wrong with it.

```
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.rating, CASE WHEN r.by=:USER_ID
           THEN r.rating ELSE 0 END AS userrating FROM `products` p 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN `ratings` r
           ON r.productid=p.id 
           WHERE p.moderated=1
           order by p.rating desc";
```

**EDIT:**

I need to list all the products, and if a user has rated the product, I need the users rating attached as "userrating"=(the users rating).

Comment: `r.by=:USER_ID` is assigning a value if a specific user id matches.

Comment: "It works with only one user, so I don't know what's wrong with it."  Hmmm, maybe there is nothing wrong with it and you don't have a question.  What is the question, by the way?

Comment: If the product doesn't have any associated ratings, then `r.rating` and `r.by` will be `NULL`. Isn't that enough to go on? You could have something like `CASE WHEN r.by IS NULL THEN r.rating ELSE 0 END`, or the more compact `COALESCE(r.rating, 0)`, or the even more compact (and probably more correct) `r.rating`, which will give the rating as `NULL` (not rated) rather than zero (presumably rated very, very poorly).

Comment: Please read the edit, if in doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.rating, CASE WHEN r.by=:USER_ID
```

To:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.rating, CASE WHEN r.by IS NOT NULL
```

Even simpler, you can replace the CASE statement with COALESCE:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.rating, COALESCE(r.rating, 0) AS userrating 
FROM `products` p
...
```

Note that if several users gave different ratings on a single product, you'll get multiple rows returned - one for each distinct rating value.

**UPDATE**

To get the ratings for a single user id (passed as `USER_ID`), the simplest method would be to filter on the outer join itself:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.rating, COALESCE(r.rating, 0) AS userrating 
FROM `products` p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `ratings` r
  ON r.productid=p.id AND r.by=:USER_ID
WHERE p.moderated=1
ORDER BY p.rating desc
```

Comment: If a user has rated the product, then the rating should the whatever he/she rated. This solution seems to give the latest (or first?) rating - not the current user's rating.

Comment: @KennethB: The original answer was for _all_ users - updated to explain how this would work for a specific user.